# heroku and db migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, heroku

```
class AddExpMonthAndExpYearToOrder < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :orders, :exp_month, :integer
    add_column :orders, :exp_year, :integer
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :orders, :exp_month
    remove_column :orders, :exp_year
  end
end
```

Have this migration, running it on heroku, but nothing changes. New fields doesnt appears in the table. Dunno where is a problem

```
Ruby console for sample.heroku.com
>> Order
=> Order(id: integer, ship_address: string, city: string, state: string, zip: string, cc_number: string, telephone: string, cart_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
>> exit
petya:geomarket > heroku rake db:migrate
(in /app)
==  AddExpMonthAndExpYearToOrder: migrating ===================================
-- add_column(:orders, :exp_month, :integer)
   -> 0.0025s
-- add_column(:orders, :exp_year, :integer)
   -> 0.0017s
==  AddExpMonthAndExpYearToOrder: migrated (0.0044s) ==========================

petya:geomarket > heroku console
Ruby console for sample.heroku.com
>> Order
=> Order(id: integer, ship_address: string, city: string, state: string, zip: string, cc_number: string, telephone: string, cart_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

On my local machine all works fine. Tried to remigrate, didnt help.

Comment: im want to keep my data plus im not sure that this method will work

Comment: Did you try this?: After running a migration you’ll want to restart your app with "heroku restart" to reload the schema and pickup any schema changes.

Comment: Are you using heroku_san gem or something to manage multiple environments?

Comment: use the --app my-app-name flag to make sure you are pointing to the right application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your DB setup locally the way you want it, and you simply want to mirror that data/schema on Heroku, try `heroku db:push`

Good luck!

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I get ``db:push` is not a heroku command`

Answer (score 1):

heroku changed their api a bit
`heroku run rake db:migrate` solves it for me

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.

Heroku is very strickt with migration naming. Try to add a 's' to the Class name as well as the filename and you will see that it works.

It worked for me, so maybe that will solve your problem as well.